# std string compare two sub strings by iterators

Tags: c++, stl

is this substrings (2) `int compare (size_t pos, size_t len, const string& str,
             size_t subpos, size_t sublen) const;` my best choice to compare two substrings if I have them by pairs of `begin, end` iterators.

Is this what I have to do, seems a bit off:

```
str1.compare(begin2 - str2.begin(), end2 - begin2, str2,
             begin1 - str1.begin(), end1 - begin1)
```

Comment: Do you just want to know if the substrings are equal/not-equal or do you want to compare them to get the "lesser" of the 2?

Comment: To expand on the above comment, see the documentation for `std::equal` and `std::mismatch`

Comment: @Chad You stole my thunder ... that is where I was heading :)

Comment: in this case I need equal, but it is good to know that there is `std::mismatch` option as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are comparing substrings for equality, you could use [`std::equal`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal) instead, like this:

```
bool res = ((end1-begin1) == (end2-begin2))
        && std::equal(begin1, end1, begin2, end2);
```

You need to compare lengths for equality before calling `std::equal` to avoid going past the end of the second range. This issue is fixed in C++14 - you would be able to do it simply as

```
bool res = std::equal(begin1, end1, begin2, end2);
```

If you are comparing substrings *lexicographically*, you can use [`std::lexicographical_compare`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lexicographical_compare), like this:

```
bool firstIsLess = std::lexicographical_compare(begin1, end1, begin2, end2);
```